# Ruby on Rails: User model association applications and migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, associations

I'm still fairly new to Ruby on Rails and I'm working with associations, such as if a table has_many :facts, or belongs_to :list,

do we deal with users as well? for Users model:

```
has_many :lists
```

and then the list model should have

```
belongs_to :user
```

Now does this mean I need to create a new column in the table? Right now I only have email and password_digest. Do I need to add a new migration to add a new column `list_id`. I already did `rake db:migrate`. Can I just simply add a column in the migration file?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend Googling "rails migrations" and following the first link.  While you're there, read the Active Record Associations guide too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must create a new column and if you already run the migration you must create a new one.

However, it's the list that must have the `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks, How does rails know which table to use when I create a new migration? for instance, if I say `rails g migration AddUserIdColumnToLists user_id:integer` or `rails g migration AddIdToLIsts user_id:integer`, will rails care about the name? What is the naming convention for this? I'm not sure how rails knows to put the user id in table list

Comment: The form should be `AddXXXToYYY` in order for rails to understand where you want to add the column. More info in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html